# how to apply multiple classes on mouseenter event using ngclass in angular 6

Tags: angular, event-handling

I am new in Angular trying to apply class using ng class expression but class doesn't apply on li element.
I want to highlight li element on the mouseover event.

```
<ul class="list-group sortable" [sortablejs]="images" [sortablejsOptions]="clone1Options">
  <li class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == item, 'highlight':hovering}" ng-init="hovering = false" ng-mouseenter="hovering=true"
ng-mouseleave="hovering=false" *ngFor="let item of images" (click)="displayImg($event, item)"><a >Element {{ item }}</a></li>
</ul>
```

can someone correct me?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using CSS selectors to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple expressions like this:

```
ng-mouseenter="hovering=true; otherClass=true" ng-mouseleave="hovering=false; otherClass=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

in your **template**

```
<li class="list-group-item" [class.active]="isActive" (mouseover)="addStyle()" (mouseout)="removeStyle()"> Some Text or element... </li>
```

add your **component.ts**

```
isActive: boolean = false;

addStyle(){
  this.isActive= true;
}
removeStyle() {
  this.isActive= false;
}
```

and you Add the css file in your stylesheet

> ```
> .list-group-item.active {
>    /* some style here...*/
> }
> ```

when mouse hover in your element then **addStyle** function cell and add your element **avtice** class and when mouse out your element then class remove. the **active** class contain some style in your stylesheet.